# YPDrawSignatureView - TableView cell duplicates

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have used YPDrawSignatureView on TableView cell, when scrolling tableview, cells are duplicate signatures, anyone knows how can solve it.

my cellForRow func:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.signatureTabelViewCell ) as! SignautreTableViewCell
      let signatureData = signature[indexPath.row]
      cell = SignautreTableViewCell.configureCell(cell: cell, forSignature: signatureData, atIndex: indexPath.row) 
      cell.delegate = self
      return cell }
```

class Signature {
    var name: String!
    var view: YPDrawSignatureView!
}

protocol DataSourceUpdateDelegate: class {
    func signatureValueChanged(cell: SignautreTableViewCell, nameChanged changedValue: String, viewChanged: YPDrawSignatureView)
}

// cell

class SignautreTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var signatureView: YPDrawSignatureView!

weak var delegate: DataSourceUpdateDelegate?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    textField.delegate = self
    signatureView.delegate = self
}


override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

}

class func configureCell(cell: SignautreTableViewCell, forSignature signature: Signature, atIndex index: Int) -> SignautreTableViewCell {

    cell.tag = index
    cell.textField.text = signature.name
    cell.signatureView = signature.view
    return cell
}



func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    self.delegate?.signatureValueChanged(cell: self, nameChanged: textField.text!, viewChanged: signatureView)
}

// Function for clearing the content of signature view
@IBAction func clearSignature(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // This is how the signature gets cleared
    self.signatureView.clear()
}

// Function for saving signature
@IBAction func saveSignature(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Getting the Signature Image from self.drawSignatureView using the method getSignature().
    if let signatureImage = self.signatureView.getSignature(scale: 10) {

        // Saving signatureImage from the line above to the Photo Roll.
        // The first time you do this, the app asks for access to your pictures.
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(signatureImage, nil, nil, nil)

        // Since the Signature is now saved to the Photo Roll, the View can be cleared anyway.
        self.signatureView.clear()
    }
}
```

}

extension SignautreTableViewCell: YPSignatureDelegate {

```
func didStart(_ view: YPDrawSignatureView) {
    print("Started Drawing")
  self.delegate?.signatureValueChanged(cell: self, nameChanged: textField.text!, viewChanged: view)

}

func didFinish(_ view: YPDrawSignatureView) {
    print("Finished Drawing")
   self.delegate?.signatureValueChanged(cell: self, nameChanged: textField.text!, viewChanged: view)
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide code so we can help you. Specifically, share the code in `CellForRow` func.

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.signatureTabelViewCell
            ) as! SignautreTableViewCell
        
        let signatureData = signature[indexPath.row]
        cell = SignautreTableViewCell.configureCell(cell: cell, forSignature: signatureData, atIndex: indexPath.row)
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

Comment: I haven't use SignautreTableViewCell but if data is duplicate then you need to use prepareForReuse method in SignautreTableViewCell and nil all components values.(label etc)

Comment: I know that, the probmel is how can set nil signatureview? Also I added cell class, please review it.